# Why not $f(z)=z^2$ conformal at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, self-learning, conformal-geometry

$$f(z)=z^2$$ is not conformal at $z=0$

Why?

---

Conformal definition:

$f$ is conformal at z if f preserves angles there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The angle between the rays $t$ and $it$ with $t\in[0,\infty)$ is $90^\circ$.
The angle between thier images $t^2$ and $-t^2$ is $180^\circ$

Answer (score 1):

For $f$ to be conformal $f'(z)\ne 0$. In your case $f'(z)|_{z=0}=0$.